# can't run mysql under my user account

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I installed mysql using Homebrew on my mac. It's the latest version of mysql (5.7.9). I followed the instructions from this [link](http://blog.joefallon.net/2013/10/install-mysql-on-mac-osx-using-homebrew/). Everything went fine until I had to run the command

```
mysql_install_db --verbose --user='whoami' --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
```

It spit out the errors

```
mysql_install_db: [ERROR] unknown variable 'tmpdir=/tmp'
2016-01-18 16:52:42 [ERROR]   Unrecognized options
```

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql_install_db` command [has been deprecated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-install-db.html) as of version 5.7.6, so the guide you linked is no longer valid:

> `mysql_install_db` is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.6 because its functionality has been integrated into `mysqld`, the MySQL server. To initialize a MySQL installation, invoke `mysqld` with the `--initialize` or `--initialize-insecure` option. For more information, see [Section 2.10.1.1, “Initializing the Data Directory Manually Using mysqld”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html). `mysql_install_db` will be removed in a future MySQL release.

Comment: you use the wrong ticks in `whoami` - try  $ echo --verbose --user='whoami' --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp , to see your parameter and change it

Comment: @ Mr. Llama - No, see the parameter --user='whoami' , there are the wrong wuotes. they must use other, copy the commandline and change mysql_install_db to echo. so you see the result

Comment: I get that `'whoami'` is probably incorrect, but you comment should be on the question, not this answer.

Comment: and ich have take a look in the help screen from mysql_install_db. there is no parameter tmpdir. remove it, or set in my.cnf